# session userdata dont show admin value

Tags: codeigniter

In database i have username, password, id, admin and etc. but my admin value not show. Why?
http://prntscr.com/ewuiz9
http://prntscr.com/ewuj4o

```
       // Get username
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        // Get and encrypt the password
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

        // Login user
        $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

        if($user_id){
            // Create session


            $user_data = array(
                'admin' => $admin,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'username' => $username,
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $user_data);

            // Set message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');

            redirect('posts');
        } else {
            // Set message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');

            redirect('users/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use md5 for passwords very unsecured. Use the php password hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/compatibility_functions.html#password_hash

Answer (score 0):

> **Because you have set it like**

```
 $user_data = array(
    'admin' => $admin,
     'user_id' => $user_id,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => true
 );

 $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $user_data);
```

> You can access it like on another controller.

```
$userdata = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

echo $userdata['username'];
```

> If you just need want to access like

`echo $this->session->userdata('username');`

Then you just need to set it like

```
 $user_data = array(
    'admin' => $admin,
     'user_id' => $user_id,
    'username' => $username,
    'logged_in' => true
 );

 $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
```

Make sure you have autoloaded session so can have access to it over website

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

On config.php make sure you have set the session path and session folder permission 0700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
In model i found that:

```
    // Log user in
    public function login($username, $password){
        // Validate
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $result = $this->db->get('users');

        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i change to:

```
    // Log user in
    function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->select('id,admin,username,password,email');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            return $query->result();
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```